# One command to find a list of file names within files in another folder

Tags: shell, command-line

I'm quite new to Unix commands and this might be really intuitive to some of you, so please forgive my ignorance.

What I want is to find all .txt files in a folder that has other sub-folders as well as files inside. Using the found list, which should be the file name and extension only (no full path), I need to search all .xml files within another folder (also have sub-folders and files and is the parent of the first searched folder) for occurrences of file names found in the first search.

Hope this is clear enough!

I tried this and it didn't work (I know, it's an absolutely beginner's try):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n" -exec find .. -name "*.xml" | xargs grep {} \;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add an example directory structure to your question with expected output.  It's not immediately clear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you seach inside the XML files? Do you use XPath?

Comment: @ Lutz Horn, doesn't matter, just text-based searching

Comment: What is "text based searching"?  Do you want to simply look for the existence of `/path/to/example.xml`, or do you want to look inside the file for something?

Comment: @ghoti, I want to find all text files in one folder and search within another folder for all XML files that contain any of the text file names. E.g., I'm looking for a.xml that contains "x.txt" inside it

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.  Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somethiing like this (untested):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n" > /tmp/a
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -HFf /tmp/a {} \;
```

Maybe add `-w` as well for word-delimited searching.

Another try at process substitution:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -HFf <(find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n") {} \;
```

Comment: @ Mark Setchell, the two commands are working but not the one liner

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it in one line for the moment - sorry. I'll keep thinking and maybe someone clever will come along and help out!

Comment: If you're using bash as the shell, you could use process redirection to eliminate the need for a temporary file.

Comment: Are you using bash? It needs bash.

Comment: I'm using bash already. Before update it told me: `grep: xx.xml: No such file or directory`, and now it's saying `grep: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec basename {} .txt \; | while read file; do grep -l "\<${file}\>\.txt" /path/to/*.xml && echo "found: $file"; done
```

Note that this solution runs the risk of breaking if special characters like space, newline, etc, are within the filename.

Comment: hmm, anything compact?

Comment: You asked for one line.  Perhaps if you explained what you wanted to *do* with the files you found, we could come up with more applicable answers.  Until then, this looks like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: interesting link! However, Mark's first answer was exactly what I want, and my problem was well understood based on this answer. All I asked afterwards was a more convenient way to do it. Now if your question was whether I am asking for X or Y the answer is X.